# change clicked item color in reccyclerview

Tags: android-recyclerview

I am using recyclerview for showing list. I want to change color of selected item in recyclerview. I am getting color on selection of item, but after scrolling multiple items getting same color in list. Please give any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution

I made global variable to store position and handled click listener in ViewHolder. Onclick of item, I changed the global position value

`textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    globalPosition=getAdapterPosition();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });`

then in onBindViewHolder

```
if(postion==globalPosition)
{
    //change color to red
    textview.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
else
{
    //change color to white of remaining items in list
    textview.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```